# Xamarin Forms "...DisplayAlert does not exist in the current context."

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I'm working with Xamarin, still new to it, but I'm having a problem that I get the feeling I shouldn't be. Here's my problem:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DataBinding_Lists
{
public class App
{
    public static Page GetMainPage ()
    {   
        var listView = new ListView { RowHeight = 40 };
        listView.ItemsSource = new Person []
        {
            new Person { FirstName = "Abe", LastName = "Lincoln" },
            new Person { FirstName = "Groucho", LastName = "Marks" },
            new Person { FirstName = "Carl", LastName = "Marks" },
        };

        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "FirstName");
        listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => {
            await DisplayAlert ("Tapped!", e.SelectedItem + " was tapped.", "OK", "");
        };

        return new ContentPage { 
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = new Thickness (5,20,5,5),
                Spacing = 10,
                Children = { listView }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

}

Obviously, I've got a class on another page called "Person." This class has two properties: "FirstName" and "LastName." When I try and put all of this together like so in Xamarin, I get the error saying: "The name 'DisplayAlert' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: That error is telling you that Xamarin doesn't know what DisplayAlert is. You're probably either missing a reference to an assembly, missing a `using` statement or both.

Comment: The _DisplayAlert_ method is used by "Xamarin.Forms," which, as stated above, I am using. DisplayAlert is a method created by and for Xamarin, so if I'm using what it tells me to, then I don't know why it's still giving me this error. (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/pop-ups/)

Comment: Yes, but it's a method of the `Page` class (not sure if it's static or member method), but you are neither calling it using `Page` prefix nor does your `App` class inherit from the `Page` class, so it has no way of knowing how to call it. You either have to do `Page.DisplayAlert()` (if it's a static method) or make your `App` class inherit from `Page` and keep the current way of calling.

Comment: I just tried both of those ideas in. They sound legit, as though they _should_ work, but with both that I tried, it said the same thing: "An object reference is required to access non-static member 'Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert(string,string,string,string)' Does this mean that instead of using a static method I should create an object to call the method?

Comment: Yeah, so it appears that `DisplayAlert()` is a member method. As such, you may not call it from a static context. So yes, you do have to call it using one of your objects, see answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this and I lean toward the second one. Close to what Edward L. has said.

`DisplayAlert` is a method on a Xamarin.Forms Page... and you are inside of a static method that is returning that page, so you have no reference to it.

So you could do this:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DataBinding_Lists
{
public class App
{
    private static Page page;
    public static Page GetMainPage ()
    {   
        var listView = new ListView { RowHeight = 40 };
        listView.ItemsSource = new Person []
        {
            new Person { FirstName = "Abe", LastName = "Lincoln" },
            new Person { FirstName = "Groucho", LastName = "Marks" },
            new Person { FirstName = "Carl", LastName = "Marks" },
        };

        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "FirstName");
        listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => {
            await page.DisplayAlert ("Tapped!", e.SelectedItem + " was tapped.", "OK", "");
        };

        page = new ContentPage { 
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = new Thickness (5,20,5,5),
                Spacing = 10,
                Children = { listView }
            }

        };
        return page;
    }

}
}
```

What you should really do is create a new class that is your page.

Your `App.cs` turns into this:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DataBinding_Lists
{
public class App
{
    public static Page GetMainPage ()
    {   
        return new PeoplePage();
    }

}
}
```

Then you create a new class that inherits from `Page`:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DataBinding_Lists
{
public class PeoplePage : Page
{
    public PeoplePage()
    {   
        var listView = new ListView { RowHeight = 40 };
        listView.ItemsSource = new Person []
        {
            new Person { FirstName = "Abe", LastName = "Lincoln" },
            new Person { FirstName = "Groucho", LastName = "Marks" },
            new Person { FirstName = "Carl", LastName = "Marks" },
        };

        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "FirstName");
        listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => {
            await DisplayAlert ("Tapped!", e.SelectedItem + " was tapped.", "OK", "");
        };

        Content = new ContentPage { 
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = new Thickness (5,20,5,5),
                Spacing = 10,
                Children = { listView }
            }

        };
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I've been working straight out of Xamarin tutorials, so it was kinda annoying that I had to go through all of this, but you _private static Page page_ idea was exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 36):

or just try to use :

```
await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "your message", "OK");
```

Comment: That works for me as well. Please note that calling this from other threads would have to be done as follows: Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async () => await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("My Alert", "My message.", "OK") );

Comment: Simplest solution presented here, no need to introduce any sort of unnecessary complexities

Answer (score 6):

`DisplayAlert()` is a method of the `Page` class.

In order for your class to be able to use it, it needs to either instantiate a `Page` object and invoke it using that object or directly inherit from it.

Since you stated that your `Person` class is actually also a `Page` class, you could also invoke it using one of your `Person` objects `i.e. personObj.DisplayAlert(...)`

Perhaps something similar to the following:

```
var personObj = new Person();
personObj.DisplayAlert ("Tapped!", e.SelectedItem + " was tapped.", "OK", "");
```

This of course, assumes that your Person class declaration goes something like the following:

```
public class Person : Page
{
    ...
}
```

Obviously, the exact implementation will depend on how you structure your code. I am just going by what I can see in your question and assuming a few things.